# Typescript React + Firestore Nested Comments Optimisation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Part of my team project at university includes a blog system. I've implemented a nested comments system with firebase. The problem with my code is that after any change is made to comments or the post, whether it's edited, deleted, or added, it queries the database from the top again. Incurring all the reads which I already have. How could I query only the missing comment? And append it to the current comments object?

Firestore Structure:
**posts/{userId}/posts/{postID}/comments/{commentId}**
Comments data:
[Comment data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8GDU.png)

```
let lastDocument: DocumentData | undefined | null;
let commentLimit = 3;
let comments: object[] = [];
const history = useHistory();
let { uid, slug } = useParams<{ uid: string, slug: string }>();
const [post, setPost] = useState<any>(SINGLE);
const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState("");
const postDocRef = doc(db, "posts", `${uid}/posts/${slug}`);
const commentCollectionRef = collection(postDocRef, "comments");
```

**Query Post:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  onSnapshot(postDocRef, async (result) => {
  lastDocument = null;
  if (result.exists()) {
    setImageURL(result.get("image").downloadURL);
    setPost({
      id: result.id,
      desc: result.get("appendix"),
      userId: result.get("userId"),
      postType: "standard",
      readingTime: calculateReadingTime(result.get("content")),
      href: `/single/${uid}/${slug}`,
      date: result.get("createdAt").toDate().toDateString(),
      featuredImage: result.get("image").downloadURL,
      like:
        {
          count: result.get("heartCount"),
          isLiked: await checkPostLiked(result.get("docID")),
        },
      bookmark: {count: 3502, isBookmarked: false},
      tags: result.get("tags"),
      comments: await getAllComments(),
      ...result.data()
    })
  } else history.push("/page404");
})}, [uid, slug]);
```

**Nest Comments:**

```
const nest = (items: any, id: number | null | undefined): any => {
  return items.filter((item: any) => item.parentId === id).map((item: any) => ({
    ...item,
    children: nest(items, item.id as number | null),
  }));
};
```

**Query Comments:**

```
const getNestedComments = async (rootComment: any) => {
  const document = await getDoc(doc(commentCollectionRef, rootComment));
  if (document.get("childrens")){
    for (let childComment of document.get("childrens")){
      comments.push(await getNestedComments(childComment));
    }
  }
  return {
    docId: document.id,
    date: document.get("createdAt").toDate().toDateString(),
    ...document.data()
  };
};


const getAllComments = async () => {
  comments = [];
  const q = (lastDocument) ?
    query(commentCollectionRef,
    where("parentId", "==", null),
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
    startAfter(lastDocument),
    limit(commentLimit))
    :
    query(commentCollectionRef,
    where("parentId", "==", null),
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
    limit(commentLimit))

  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);

  for (let commentDoc of snapshot.docs){
    if (commentDoc.get("childrens")){
      for (let comment of commentDoc.get("childrens")){
        comments.push(await getNestedComments(comment));
      }
    }
    comments.push({
      docId: commentDoc.id,
      date: commentDoc.get("createdAt").toDate().toDateString(),
      ...commentDoc.data()
    })
  }
  lastDocument = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
  return nest(comments, null);
}


// Get More comments
const handleMoreComments = async () => {
  comments = [];
  setPost({
    ...post,
    comments: [...post.comments.concat(await getAllComments())]
  })
}
```

The above method does work. However, is a terrible solution from a scaling standpoint. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> after any change is made to comments or the post, [it incurs] all the reads which I already have

If you [enable local persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) in the SDK, any documents that are unmodified will be read from the cache instead of having to be reread from the server.

You can then still process `snapshot.docs`, but unmodified documents will be coming from the local cache. Alternatively, you can process `snapshot.docChanges` and [handle only the changed documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) between the previous snapshot and this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it! Just want to clarify that if I enable local persistence, I will be able to use the code as-is and any different document will be read from the server?  and only charged for documents read from the server?

Comment: You're only charged when a document needs t be read for you from the server. Reads from the local cache are indeed not charged.